# Laravel Queue using Redis driver

Tags: laravel, redis

How to show the list of queue, job_batches, failed_jobs in Laravel using Redis as queue driver? or that table usually don't need for Redis? I tried to use database as my driver. Thank you

Comment: Hi Welcome to SO..You can take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/horizon. its provides a beautiful dashboard and code-driven configuration for your Laravel powered Redis queues.

Comment: Yes, I visited the documentation, but what if I want to make my own dashboard? Thanks